# How could I only recognize certain phrases in CMU Sphinx?

Tags: java, android, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I have a grammar like this:

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar actions;

public <item> = save this story | skip this story | stop the news;
```

However, it recognizes everything that remotely matches these phrases. Is there a way for me to only recognize the phrase if they actually say it?

I'm currently using this code to load the grammar:

```
File actionsGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/actions.gram");
recognizer.addGrammarSearch("actions", actionsGrammar);
```

E.g. saying `save blah blah this blah blah story` should not match, and neither should `bake chris boring`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use pocketsphinx in keyword spotting mode. There is no keyword spotting mode in sphinx4 yet.

You can find Android demo here

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid